# join two tables along with count of records from second table based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have following tables -

Here is [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7db7d/2/2)

*categories*

```
+-----------+-------------+
|  column   |    type     |
+-----------+-------------+
| id        | int(11)     |
| name      | varchar(40) |
| unit      | varchar(50) |
| is_active | tinyint(1)  |
+-----------+-------------+
```

and

*products*

```
+-------------+---------------+
|   column    |     type      |
+-------------+---------------+
| id          | int(11)       |
| category_id | int(11)       |
| name        | varchar(40)   |
| base_rate   | decimal(10,2) |
| is_active   | tinyint(1)    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I want to get list of categories along with count of number of products active. If no products are active for a category it should return 0.

Somewhat like table below -

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id |  name  | active_count |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 | Steel  |            1 |
|  2 | Cement |            2 |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

I have come up with following query -

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.unit, COUNT(p.category_id) as active_count 
FROM `categories` c 
JOIN `products` p
    ON c.id = p.category_id
WHERE ( p.is_active = 1 )
GROUP BY p.category_id;
```

This above **query works only when there is at least one product active** in each of category. If there are not products available it should return `active_count` as **0**

How can I fix this ?

Here is [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7db7d/2/2)

Comment: Your GROUP BY is "inside out"... Do `GROUP BY c.id, c.name, c.uni`. I.e. the columns you select that are not arguments to any aggregate functions, are the ones supposed to be listed in the group by clause.

Comment: @jarlh That's right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.unit, COUNT(p.category_id) as active_count 
FROM `categories` c 
LEFT JOIN `products` p
    ON c.id = p.category_id AND p.is_active = 1 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

It is also important to move predicate `p.is_active = 1` from `WHERE` clause to `ON`, so that *all* records of `categories` table are returned by the query.

Comment: I tried. But if there are no products active for a category it should return count as 0 for such category. With this query the category having no products active get omitted from results.

Comment: You nailed it. :) Thank you very much. I didn't knew multiple predicates are allowed in `ON` clause.